# iOS sims hang up on session initialization

Tags: appium

I set the capability

"noReset": true,

but sometimes, my iOS sims hang up on sessions creation, and I have to kill and restart them. Anyone else have a similar experience? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Practically all my problems with the server errors and slow driver initializations and hang-ups have been solved by simply clearing the ports that the Appium servers and drivers use before initializing any new servers or drivers; on linux this has been accomplished by killing all the processes that use a port with this command:

```
lsof -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER}| awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but only this helped.
Just add capability: `waitForQuiescence = false`